# parse error in nested if/do blocks

Tags: haskell

```
defaultFileName :: [Char]
defaultFileName = "Test.log"

defaultSearchName :: String
defaultSearchName = "xyz"
```

This code can be compiled:

```
a3 :: Int -> [[Char]] -> IO [Char]
a3 index arg = 
  if null arg
    then do
      a <- putStrLn "No parameters have been passed."
      a <- putStrLn $ "1 Default search string: " ++ defaultSearchName
      a <- putStrLn ("2 Default file name: " ++ defaultFileName)
      return defaultFileName
    else return (arg!!index)
```

once I add an extra IF-THEN-ELSE, I cannot compile it anymore

```
a3 :: Int -> [[Char]] -> IO [Char]
a3 index arg = 
  if null arg
    then do
      a <- putStrLn "No parameters have been passed."
      a <- putStrLn $ "1 Default search string: " ++ defaultSearchName
      a <- putStrLn ("2 Default file name: " ++ defaultFileName)
      if index == 0
        then  return defaultSearchName
        else return defaultFileName
    else return (arg!!index)
```

why???? It is so frustrating with every single step.

Comment: I forgotten to put the compile error, which is:
parse error on input `if'

Comment: The error is right there under you inserted `if` - it's a **fat** ugly tab right there (note: you will see this if you edit your answer here - SO will reformat the markdown and remove the tab in this view)

Answer (score 5):

Your code compiles fine. Are you sure you don't have tabs and spaces interleaved there as an indentation?

Try `ghci -fwarn-tabs yourfile.hs`

Comment: Wouldn't this be more appropriate as a comment?

Comment: @Jubobs kind of, but it's overwhelmingly likely that tabs are indeed the culprit.

Comment: Indeed, there are tabs in the pasted code (we need to press "edit" to see them).

Comment: @Carsten Sometimes I wish `-Wall` were the default. Even the perl man page lists "-w is not the default" in the BUGS section, IIRC ;-)

Comment: @Carsten: GHC-7.10 _does_ warn about tabs by default, so we shouldn't have this problem for too long anymore.

Comment: @leftaroundabout really? **great** - never noticed (well my editor helps me out of that mess) so thank you for letting me know (feeling like an ass now... have to delete some comments)

Comment: Thank you all for your help.Indeed this was related to tabs (which I thought I double checked - clearly not good enough)

Comment: @user1863063 If phadej solved your problem, please consider accepting his answer.